# How to solve java printf issue ("source not found.") on Eclipse debugger window, when the same printf method prints it out correctly on the console?

Tags: java, eclipse, printf

My code didn't run, so I worked with the eclipse debugger, and as soon as I got to that printf part, it showed an error message: source not found.

[Here is the debugger error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrApv.png)However, it still prints out find on the console, and it is only showing the error message on the debugger window, and would not let me proceed to next lines where my "real" errors exist.
[Here is the stacktrace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUZj9.png)

```
System.out.printf("a: %d\n", curElement.a);
System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d   ", curElement.a, curElement.b, curElement.c, curElement.io);
```

Those two lines above seem to be having that "source not found" error on the debugger window. 
Could you please help me with fixing the issue with my printf? Thank you.

```
public class Scheduling2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        String fileAddress = args[0];
        File fileInput  = new File(fileAddress); //Read
        Scanner scan    = new Scanner(fileInput);
        int numProcesses  = scan.nextInt();
        Queue<Process> processes = new LinkedList<Process>();
        ArrayList<Process> allProcesses = new ArrayList<Process>();
        //LinkedList processes = new LinkedList(); //No need to define the size
        int currNumProcesses = 0;

        //Adding each process to processes queue
        for (int m = 0; m < numProcesses; m++) {
            int a = scan.nextInt();
            int b = scan.nextInt();
            int c = scan.nextInt();
            int io = scan.nextInt();
            Process thisProcess = new Process(a, b, c, io); 
            thisProcess.id = m;
            processes.add(thisProcess);
            allProcesses.add(thisProcess);
            currNumProcesses++;
        }
        printQueue(processes, numProcesses);
        FCFS(processes, numProcesses, allProcesses);
        printQueue(processes, numProcesses);
    }   
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.printf(" Error: File not foundd. \n");
    }
}
public static void printQueue (Queue processes, int numProcesses) {
    Process curElement = (Process) processes.poll();
    System.out.printf("The original input was:  ");
    while(curElement != null) { 
        System.out.printf("a: %d\n", curElement.a);
        System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d   ", curElement.a, curElement.b, curElement.c, curElement.io);
        curElement = (Process) processes.poll();
    }
    System.out.print("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message that you're getting, including the stacktrace. Don't paraphrase the error message.

Comment: "Source not found" just means it can't find the source.  It presumably still has the "compiled" code.  Please just tell us the error!

Comment: Added the screenshot of the debugger error, and the console error. "source not found" was not the paraphrased error message, as that is what is actually shown on the debugger window. Thanks for the feedback and please let me know if there are any other information I can provide to make it easy for you.

Comment: stacktrace! stacktrace! stacktrace!

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if I provided the stacktrace correctly. Please advise.

Comment: No, the stacktrace is what is in your second image.
Which states that it can't find your random-numbers.txt file -> Check that.

Comment: Problem was solved - thank you for all your help. I realized that source not found message does not actually stop me from proceeding to the next line -- I can press step return if I would like to ignore the message and proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the debugger, when you "step into" any method, it attempts to show you the source for that method. If it cannot find the source, it still might be able to step, but cannot show you the corresponding source. If it cannot step, it can still execute the code.

Your "FileNotFound" exception tells you that it cannot find the file your code attempts to open (or maybe a folder in which you're attempting to create a file). Keep in mind that any relative file location depends on knowing the "default directory" in which the process running your code starts with. You can solve that problem by ensuring you have only absolute file locations (i.e., ones that start with the root directory on the drive), though that can be a problem for writing programs to run on different machines. For an exercise while learning, though, I think it's fine to do that.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, I realized from your solution that if the debugger cannot find the source, it will state source not found, but I can still proceed to the next lines by clicking "step return".